# How to verify if search result has more than one result?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Can anyone please help how to find a search result has more than one results using selenium and TestNG. Scenario is as follows:

1. Launch www.amazon.com
2. Enter search string in search box and click search

Now verify search result has more then 1 result(>1). Following is the line which I thought of `Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected, delta);`. Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try the below code. It fetches all the search results and then checks if the count is greater than 1 or not, then prints accordingly. :-**

```
    driver.get("http://www.amazon.in/");

    driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys("bagsasdfafds");

    int count = driver.findElements(By.className("suggest_link")).size();

    Assert.assertTrue(count>=1);
    System.out.println("Count is greater than or equal to 1. Count is: "+count);//This line will ONLY be printed if the count is greater than or equal to 1.
```

Comment: In this way test will pass in both cases like even if it is less than 1. I want to put a assertion for this so that if it is less than 1 the test should fail.

Comment: @Venki: Check now please.. Have used **Assert class**.. Do import it using the code `import junit.framework.Assert;` at the top.